# TokenCache: No matching token was found in the cache, Azure AD Api

Tags: azure-active-directory, access-token

I'd like to use Azure AD Api and I couldn't acquire token some reason. I have two methods, and I got this after calling:

```
       TokenCache: No matching token was found in the cache iisexpress.exe Information: 0
```

Here's my code:

```
    public string GetToken()
    {
        string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/";
        string clientId = "";
        string secret = "";
        string resource = "https://graph.windows.net/";

        var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, secret);
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

        //I think the problem is here:
        var token = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, credential).Result.AccessToken;

        return token;
    }

    public string MakeRequest()
    {
        string accessToken = GetToken();
        var tenantId = "";
        string graphResourceId = "https://graph.windows.net/";

        Uri servicePointUri = new Uri(graphResourceId);
        Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(servicePointUri, tenantId);

        ActiveDirectoryClient client = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot, async () => await Task.FromResult(accessToken));

        foreach (var user in client.Users.ExecuteAsync().Result.CurrentPage)
            Console.WriteLine(user.DisplayName);

        var client1 = new HttpClient();
        var uri = "https://graph.windows.net/" + tenantId + "/users?api-version=1.6";
        client1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

        var response = client1.GetAsync(uri).Result;
        var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        return result;
    }
```

I don't know what's the problem, and I didn't find any great hint, under other questions and a little explanation would be helpful. I'd like to understand this part, of course.

Comment: What's the detailed error you got and which line of code? The code seems to be correct. Did you have the enough permission to list the users? For example, we need the `User.Read.All` or `Directory.Read.All`  permissions to perform this REST. You can decode the access token from [this site](https://jwt.io/) and check the `roles` claim.

Comment: iisexpress.exe Information: ... - AcquireTokenHandlerBase: === Token Acquisition started:
 Authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/
 Resource: https://graph.windows.net/
 ClientId: ....
 CacheType: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.TokenCache (0 items)
 Authentication Target: Client
 
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory Information: 2 : ... - TokenCache: No matching token was found in the cache
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : ... - TokenCache: No matching token was found in the cache.         

(Roles seem to be ok anyway)

Comment: This is the log of adal. It is expected that when you execute the method first time that not able to get the token from cache. Did you mean that you didn't have any exception but only get the above log?

Comment: Yes, I didn't get exception. I tried to display the result after push a button, and I got this and the site just loading... Maybe should try write it async?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- //When you are calling

Main() {   Method_A() }

aync Method_A() {   await Method_B() }

Task < T > Method_B() {   return T; }

//It will through the error. //Need to keep Mehtod_B in another Task and run.

// Here I am avoiding few asyncs

Main() {   Method_A() }

Method_A() {   Method_B().Wait() }

Task Method_B() {   return T; }

Answer (score 0):

There is no output using the  `Console.WriteLine` in a IIS progress. If you want to output the result in a output window for the web project, you can use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()` method.

Comment: Oh, thanks! But still doesn't work... I don't know why loading and don't get the token. Got the log after that line:             var token = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, credential).Result.AccessToken;

Comment: What's version of ADAL were you developing and how did you check the log? I also suggest that you debugging the code if it is possible to check whether the code works as expected.

Comment: ADAL version is 2.14.0.0, and I got this log after the line I mentioned before.

Comment: The code seems to be correct. Are you able to get the access token successfully? And since there is no error and exception, can you explain what doesn't work mean? `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()` will send the output to the output window of Visual Studio. Did you check the log through that window or a text file?

Comment: As I see the problem is the permissions, but I added permissions within Azure Ad, but the exception is: {"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."}}}

Comment: To list the users, we need add the `User.Read.All` permission. After adding the permission on the portal, we need to click the **Grant Permissions** button. Then you check the corresponding `roles` claim by decoding the token from [this site](https://jwt.io/). And it may need a few time to make the changing work.